# what is the best way to do with Angular 8 so that in an input I can only enter text?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs

I'm trying to make the input only accept text, nothing else.

I tried to do with **ng-pattern="/^[a-za-z]*$/"** but it doesn't work

```
<form [formGroup]="reactiveForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
    <div class="form-group">
          <input type="text" id="input-name" name="name" placeholder="Nom ..." formControlName="name" [pattern]="unamePattern"/>
      <input type="submit" class="submit-button" value="Embarquer">
    </div>
  </form>
```

**ts.file**

```
 unamePattern: any = '^[a-zA-Z ]*$';
  reactiveForm = new FormGroup({
    name: new FormControl()
  });


  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient, private formBuilder: FormBuilder) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getMethod();
  }

  postMethod() {
    let myFormData = new FormData();
    myFormData.append('name', this.reactiveForm.value.name);

    return this.httpClient.post(this.postUrl, myFormData,
      { responseType: 'text' }).subscribe(
        (response) => this.array.push(response),
        (error) => console.log(error)
      );
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

When initializing your formGroup, write this for name feild:

```
name: [
   '',
   [
     Validators.pattern('^[a-zA-Z ]*$')
   ]
],
```

This is a custom validator that allows only uppercase and lowercase letters to be entered.
If you want to completely eliminate the ability to enter numbers and special characters, you should implement the onKeyDown event listener and check the value for every entered character.

```js
 function onKeyDown(e) {
      if(e.keyCode < 65 || e.keyCode > 122) {
        e.preventDefault();
        return false;
      }
}
```

```html
<input id="letters-only" type="text" onKeyDown="onKeyDown(event)" />
```

Comment: That would show an validation error, but would not stop other characters to be entered.

Comment: @MoxxiManagarm you're right, I didn't understand the question well. I updated the answer.